# Delete objects in CollectionView from UIActivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiactivity

I'm having trouble trying to delete multiple objects selected in an `UICollectionView` from my own `UIActivity`.

**FilesCollectionController.h**

```
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

This collection view uses file paths to show images.

**FilesCollectionController.m**

```
...  
ActivityTrash *trash = [[ActivityTrash alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *customActivities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:trash, nil];

UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsSelected applicationActivities:customActivities];
UINavigationController *destNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
...
// Present the Navigation controller
[self presentViewController:destNav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**ActivityTrash.h**

```
@interface ActivityTrash : UIActivity 

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *objectsToDelete;

@end
```

**ActivityTrash.m**

```
@implementation ActivityTrash

- (NSString *) activityTitle {
    return @"Delete";
}

- (UIImage *) activityImage {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadTrash"];
    }
    else
    {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphoneTrash"];
    }
}

- (BOOL) canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    return ([activityItems count] != 0);
}

- (void) prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    self.objectsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSURL *url in activityItems) {
        [self.objectsToDelete addObject:[url path]];
    }
}

- (UIViewController *) activityViewController
{
    return nil;
}


- (void)performActivity {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete file(s)"
                                                    message:@"Are you sure ?"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // If the user pressed ok, delete each image which path is in objectsToDelete
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        for (NSString *pathImage in self.objectsToDelete) {
            [DocumentManager deleteImageWithPath:pathImage];
        }
    }
    [self activityDidFinish:YES];
}
```

Files are actually deleted. But the problem is that I would like to call `[self.collectionView reloadData]` in my **FilesCollectionController** right after `UIActivity` did finish, and so my collection view would be updated immediately...

Comment: What `UIActivity`? Do you mean `UIAlertView`?

Comment: @rmaddy We can say that, UIActivity finishes after user clicked on one UIAlertView button

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way to achieve it :

**ActivityTrash.h**

```
@class FilesCollectionController;
@interface ActivityTrash : UIActivity {
    FilesCollectionController *collectionVC;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *objectsToDelete;

- (id)initFromViewController:(FilesCollectionController *)vc;

@end
```

**ActivityTrash.m**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // If the user pressed ok
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        for (NSString *pathImage in self.objectsToDelete) {
            [DocumentManager deleteImageWithPath:pathImage];
        }
    }

    [collectionVC viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self activityDidFinish:YES];
}
```

**FilesCollectionController.m**

```
ActivityTrash *trash = [[ActivityTrash alloc] initFromViewController:self];
```

May not be the best solution but it works.